# SQL update column depending on other column

Tags: sql, t-sql

```
sequenceNo    IsPoint     PointNumber      PointSequenceNumber     IsCancel
1             1                 3168                1                 1
2             0                  NULL               2                 1
3             1                  3169               2                 1
4             1                  2806               3                 1
5             1                  33322              4                 1
6             1                  2807               5                 1
7             1                  2044               6                 1
8             1                  2046               7                 1
9             0                  NULL               8                 1
10            1                  27524              8                 1
11            1                   670               9                 0
12            1                   671               10                0
13            1                   672               11                0
14            0                   NULL              12                1
15            1                   1074              12                1
16            1                   10844             13                0
17            1                   1421              14                0
```

I need to insert PointNumber to other table depending on value of IsCancel Column if IsCancel is set to 1 I need to insert first iscancel and last IsCancel  but sequentially

e.g. STARTPOINT  => above sequenceNo  1 for point number 3168 and Iscancel set to 1 I need that point to store in other table  StartPoint

ENDPOINT => above sequenceNo  15 for point number 1074 and Iscancel set to 1 I need that point to store in other table as Endpoint

TotalCANCELED => Column hold COUNT  IsCancel  but only if PointNumber is not NULL

I need to update these columns in other table with following numbers depending on above table

```
STARTPOINT         ENDPOINT             TOTALCANCEL

3168                 1074                  9
```

Thanks community

Answer (score 0):

I find this logic a bit hard to follow.  If I understand this correctly, you can use aggregation -- although you need a little twist to get the end point number:

```
select max(case when PointSequenceNumber = 1 then pointnumber end) as startpoint,
       max(case when PointSequenceNumber = psn then pointnumber end) as endpoint,
       sum(case when isCancel = 1 and PointNumber is not null end) as totalCancel
from (select t.*,
             max(case when isCancel = 1 and PointNumber is not null then PointSequenceNumber end) over () as max_psn
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon PointSequenceNumber can be any number 1,13,22,111 depend on point

Comment: Max(sequncenumber)=lastpoint    and count(Iscancel) where pointnumber is not null